# How add validation message in hr module in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

In hr module ,hr.employee class has following fields so for this fields i wanted have valid phone number with 10 numbers only if i enter more than 10 numbers it should show message like enter valid num

```
'work_phone': fields.char('Work Phone', readonly=False),
'mobile_phone': fields.char('Work Mobile', readonly=False),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def is_phone(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    record = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
    pattern ="^[0-9]{10}$"
    for data in record:
        if re.match(pattern, data.phone):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return {}

_constraints = [(is_phone, 'Error: Invalid phone', ['phone']), ]
```

This way you can match the phone number with regular expression.

View side

```
<fields name="phone" onchange="is_phone()">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use onchange method to get warning on invalid chars in field,
then try this:

```
 def onchange_mobile(self, cr, uid, ids, mobile, context=None):
    res = {}
    if not mobile:
         return res

    if not mobile.isdigit():
        # raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid phone'),_('Please enter a valid phone'))
        res['warning'] = "Phone number %s is invalid, please use only digits!" % mobile
        res['value']['mobile'] = False   # just erase the value entered
    return res
```

Or, you can override thw write method of your working class and raise error if field 'mobile' is not numeric... like

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    if 'mobile' in vals.keys() and not vals['mobile'].isdigit():
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid phone'),_('Please enter a valid phone'))
    return super(your_class, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_change('number'):
    Check here length of number greater than 10 or not if greater, then rais or validate error

view side
<Fields name="name" onchange="on_change('number')">
```

or

use **constraints** the batter

or 
check in **create** method

Comment: please add code here and should i use it hr module only